# How can I save whole package of Rails App including gems being used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm using a lot of gems. They are really sensitive about dependencies each other.
Now, current combination of the gems is just perfect. I want to save this whole App, and re-use this when I'm going on next project.

As you know, the gems are not promised to exist in the future in `rubygem.org`
So I'd like to save whole package of both App and gems being used.
Then I don't need to care about setting up gems unless I need new gem.
All I need to care about is just coding in next project.

Someone told me to use this command and save whole App folder

```
bundle install --path=vendor/bundle
```

After this, my app got screwed :(
jQuery came not to work anymore after `recompile`

So I did need to replace whole App folder with old one, which was reffering the gem in `/usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1`

Now, `jQuery` works fine after `recompile` :)

For this situation, how can I save whole package of both App and gems being used for it?

What I wanna do is, I only want to set up Ruby's correct version and MySQL.
Then I'd like to put this package into it and start coding, not deploying environment about gems!!

Can anyone share idea about this, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Answer to your question

Bundler's [`bundle package --all`](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/bundle_package.html) command will lock and cache all of your gem files into `./vendor/cache`, and you can run `bundle install --local` so it won't check rubygems.org in the future.

### Comments on your question

This question made me cringe because, while I understand the interest in having a "base image" that you know works, it sounds like a few problems will spill over to other projects.

1. Overburdened applications

   - Does each project really need all the same dependencies?
   - If not, then you are bloating each install with unneeded dependencies.
2. Brittle dependencies

   - You mention that your dependencies are very sensitive to each other, which sets off alarms.
   - I don't fully understand what you mean by that, but it sounds like you should consider finding dependencies with more stable interfaces.
   - Check out ruby-toolbox.com and keep an eye on the "Released" date.
3. Outdated dependencies

   - Locking down versions means your new applications will not benefit from updates by the maintainers.
   - (example) if you locked your rails dependency to 3.2.8 and continue to use it, you open yourself (and customers) to several major security holes.
   - (possible fix) Look at [pessimistic version constraints](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16) to allow your applications to receive non-breaking fixes.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) No one does this way? what I'm really afraid of the loss of gems. They might be gone from rubyorg in the future so that I won't be able to use them anymore. How do you guys take care of this possible problem?

Comment: rubygems' policy is not to delete content, so old gems and old versions for those gems will (almost) always be available. There are only very rare cases where a maintainer may want to remove a version (via the `gem yank` command), but this is typically only for issues like accidentally including a password in the source code.

Comment: If you have a certain gem that has to be a specific version in order to work with your code, you can specify the exact version in the gemfile. However, I would suggest trying to use the most recent version for each new project so you are kept up to date with fixes.

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer. I'll keep it in my mind, and decided to follow your suggestion. Thanks:)

Comment: Just came across this, which might be interesting. thoughtbot has a gem it uses to generate rails apps with basic changes made/populated. https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders