# Deploy Rails 3 with Phusion Passenger on Ubuntu WITH ALL GEMS INCLUDED

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, rubygems, bundler, passenger

I need to deploy a Rails 3/Phusion Passenger/Apache2 app to an Ubuntu 12.04 server without installing ANY gems on the server.

I can install any Debian packages.

How can I include all needed gems (including Rails, a couple of gems installed from git projects on github, and a bunch of regular gems installed from rubygems.org) *inside* my project so that, after deployment, Passenger will find Rails and all the gems and be happy?

(I know many people will probably be curious WHY I would want to do this. I can't talk about that, unfortunately. Sorry.)

Here are some things that have not worked. One of them might work if revised a little, I don't know:

**Failed method 1:**

1. On Ubuntu 12.04 dev machine. Ruby 1.9.3. Bundler 1.3.5. bundle package --all. Git commit.
2. On Ubuntu 12.04 server machine (gem installation from Internet not possible). Deploy project files and install packages (apache2, ruby1.9.3, ruby-bundler, rubygems, libapache2-mod-passenger which brings ruby1.8 with it). bundle -v gives Bundler version 1.0.15 (from ruby-bundler package). Make sure .bundle/config file from dev machine is also deployed. bundle install --local tries to download git gems from github, so fail.

Comment: Trying using `gem unpack` as shown in [this article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/02/24/how-to-have-bundler-load-a-custom-gem-into-a-rails-3-app/). Hopefully that works better than the two things you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Download the bundler 1.3.5 gem from http://rubygems.org/downloads/bundler-1.3.5.gem and put it in vendor/
- In an Ubuntu 12.04 vm, do bundle package --all. Git commit and push.
- Clone on the Ubuntu server.
- apt-get install each of apache2, ruby1.9.3, etc. (not rubygems or ruby-bundler. Both provide an old version of Rubygems and Bundler. A newer version of rubygems is included in the ruby1.9.3 package.)
- Follow ALL of the instructions in section 2.3 at http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu
- Make sure you have the right Ruby and Rubygems versions set to the ruby and gem commands:

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.3 200
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gem gem /usr/bin/gem1.9.3 200

(Phusion Passenger doesn't care about this, but it's probably a good idea for the gems we are about to install and for debugging stuff with the Rails console or whatever in the future.)

- gem install --local vendor/bundler-1.3.5.gem
- bundle install --local
- Set up all your other Apache config...
- service apache2 restart

Answer (score 1):

Try using `bundle package --all`, which should save your gems into `./vendor/cache`. You could also unpack the gems on your local environment with `gem unpack --target vendor` to save them in the vendor directory. Then you can give a location in the Gemfile so that your application can find the gems. Can you just not use the network to install gems, or are you really not allowed to install gems in any way?

**Sources:**
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227700/how-can-i-save-whole-package-of-rails-app-including-gems-being-used),
[2](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/02/24/how-to-have-bundler-load-a-custom-gem-into-a-rails-3-app/)

Comment: +1 for now. Haven't had a chance to try this all the way through to see if it will work yet.

Comment: @David Yeah, I didn't test it either. Let me know how it goes, and I'll try to help find a solution.

Comment: How should I make the deployed app aware of the gems? I can't install bundler with gem install. There are ruby-bundler and rubygems debian packages available on Ubuntu 12.04, but /usr/bin/bundle -v reports "Bundler version 1.0.15," which is a little old. I guess if it works, though, it works.

Comment: @David I think you might just have to go with the package, because if you can't install using rubygems, then I can't think of any other way of install bundler.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [pkgr](http://crohr.me/pkgr/) tool, which can convert your Rails app and all dependencies into a single installable Debian package.

Comment: Sorry for being lazy and not doing my own research, but it says it only works with wheezy? Not Ubuntu 12.04 precise?